# Why are my plot labels changing despite being generated in a function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code that generates a plot and saves the plot as a `.png` file in the current directory. For some reason, one plot is generated with text that fits on the plot panel and the 2nd plot (generated by the same code) actually enlarges the axis-text labels. Can any one explain this behavior?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os


def get_basename(fp):
    "Get the basename of filepath such that /PATH/TO/FILE.csv returns FILE"
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fp))[0]


def get_model_type(fp, prefix):
    """All files represent models either 'linear' or 'quad'.
    For instance all files are either linear_*_out.csv or quad_*_out.csv,
    this function will filter a the list based on desired prefix"""
    return filter(lambda x: get_basename(x).startswith(prefix), file_paths)


def read_assign(fp, col_name):
    """This function will read in the csv from input file path and assign
    unique column identifier of the specific model. This will be important
    when plotting the data"""
    return pd.read_csv(fp).assign(model_id=col_name)


def produce_plot(df, plotname):
    color_labels = df['model_id'].unique()
    color_pal = ['black', 'red', 'cyan', 'brown', 'purple']
    color_map = dict(zip(color_labels, color_pal))

    grouped_sim = df.groupby('model_id')
    for key, group in grouped_sim:
        plt.plot(group['average_fuel_T'], group['avg_th_cond'],
                 label=key, color=color_map[key])

    plt.ylabel('Thermal Conductivity', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)', fontsize=20)
    plt.legend(loc="upper left", prop=dict(weight='bold'))
    plt.grid(b=True, which="major", axis="both", linestyle="-.")
    plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
    plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=15)
    plt.savefig(plotname)
    plt.close()


working_dir = os.path.abspath('.')
file_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(working_dir, '*_out.csv'))

linear_files = get_model_type(file_paths, 'linear')
linear_model_ids = [get_basename(file) for file in linear_files]
quad_files = get_model_type(file_paths, 'quad')
quad_model_ids = [get_basename(file) for file in quad_files]

raw_linear_dat = pd.concat(map(read_assign, linear_files, linear_model_ids))
raw_quad_dat = pd.concat(map(read_assign, quad_files, quad_model_ids))

produce_plot(raw_linear_dat, 'linear_temp_cond.png')
produce_plot(raw_quad_dat, 'quad_temp_cond.png')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding plt.figure() before the loop inside the function? just to make sure you are starting with clean memory? Just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the rc params after creating the axes. Hence they will not apply to that axes, but only to the next one.

Make sure to set rcParameters which apply to the axes before creating the axes.

```
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=15)
#only after that call...
plt.plot(...)
```